# What files do I delete to have my display configuration automatically detected again?

Tags: lubuntu, 16.04, xorg

After numerous do-release-upgrades from 14.04, I'm have issues with my LCD display.

Can I just delete /etc/X11 and it will all recreate itself? Or what exactly can be done?

Comment: What kind of issues are you having?

Comment: My laptop display won't turn on on-boot. I have to let the laptop boot up and put it into sleep mode. The monitor will turn on coming out of sleep mode and allow me to login. This only occured coming from 15.08(?). The version before Xenial.

Comment: There is no 15.08,  there is 15.04 and 15.10

Comment: Also how can there be numerous do-release-upgrade? There can be numreous upgrades and dist-upgrades but do-release upgrade occurs only once every 6 months or for those preferring only LTS vrsions every 2 years

Comment: What is the output of dpkg --configure -a

Comment: blank output.. nothing

Comment: That's good.  What is the output of `ls -lh ~/.Xauthority`?

Comment: -rw------- 1 user user 53 Jun  9 08:47 /home/user/.Xauthority